# What will happen to a particle in a vortex?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

Consider a particle starting at rest at a position $(L, 0)$ in a coordinate system with polar coordinates (R, $\theta$). Act on the particle with a force $(0, C)$ in the same coordinates. I.e. an asimutal force. Will the particle spiral outwards? If yes, can you explain this in a concise way?

I'm wondering because I'm studying a particle with mass moving in a made-up ocean current described by $\frac{2\pi}{T}[-y, x]$.

Edit: The correct expression does not have $R^2$. I have fixed it now.

Edit: I'm thinking that the particle will have a velocity making an angle outward with the tangent of the circle, but I can't explain why.

Comment: Apparently something is missing here. If the force is constant and there are no other forces, the particle will move along y-axis with constant acceleration.

Comment: @rmhleo the force is expressed in polar coordinates, so always perpendicular to the radial vector.

Comment: There must be some forces that permit your current to be maintained in that way - specifically, it appears the velocity increases with radius squared (am I interpreting that correctly?), in which case you will have to consider that the vortex will result in a deformation of the surface of the water. This produces a pressure gradient so the water doesn't "disappear". Can you try to take that into account?

Comment: In that case, the force acts on the direction of $\hat{\theta}$ for the given coordinates of the particle. If this is the case, the particle must spiral outwards, because the force acts all the time at an angle with the motion direction, hence a radial component remains always, explaining the outwards drift.

Comment: Floris: I would rather not, let's just imagine the vector field is purely mathematical. The physical part was just to show that this is also relevant in physics. rmhleo: I don't understand how the force-vector which is in the asimutal direction is at an angle with the velocity.